# Proof that Euclidean norm is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^n$ using openness of open annulus,

Tags: general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^+, f(x)=|x|$ denote the Euclidean norm on $\mathbb{R}^n$, and consider the open annulus $A = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n : a<|x|<b\}$. How can we show that $f$ is continuous, using the fact that $A$ is an open set? My attempt: $f$ is continuous iff the preimage of every open set in $\mathbb{R}^+$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We know $(a,b)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^+$ and that its preimage $A$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^n$. We also know that every open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ (and therefore of $\mathbb{R}^+$) is a union of at most countably many open intervals. So let $B$ be open in $\mathbb{R}^+$, then $B=(a_1,b_1) \cup (a_2,b_2) \cup...$, at most countable. Its preimage $f^{-1}(B)$has to be open in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but I'm having trouble describing it in terms of open annuli and showing it is open.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_i f^{-1}(a_i,b_i)=\bigcup_i \{x: a_i <|x|<b_i\}$ and union of any collection of open sets is always open.

Comment: this is what I had in mind for $f^{-1}(B)$ but I couldn't get my mind around why it is equal to that union, would you mind showing me a proof why? It might be very simple but damn it eludes me atm. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @JBuck For any function $f$ and any family of stes $(A_i)$ we always have $f^{-1}(\bigcup A_i)=\bigcup f^{-1}( A_i)$. Just verify that each side is contained in the other.